# Android Studio: :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android, build

Today I was just working on my app and out of a sudden I couldn't run my app anymore.

I keep getting this message: (see screenshot for more info)

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> -1
```

I hope someone can help me! I have spend the entire day debugging this and i still haven't found te problem.

If i run it with --info i get the following message:

[image: If i run it with --info i get the following message:]

Comment: Check all your resource files. Files under `res` folder and make sure that they are all valid type.

Comment: Verify if your resources are valid. specially with vector and strings. Also, verify in which screen it happens and after you can verify the resources that are inside that screen